# Loop for dealing cards up to a determined value

Tags: javascript, loops, playing-cards

I need to come up with a loop that deals cards from a shuffled deck while the value is below or equal to a set stopAtValue of the player.
I have an array of card, Deck, which I shuffle using a shuffle function. If I .shift a card from the deck I get this format:

```
Card { value: 13, name: 'K', suit: '♥' }
```

I have a player:

```
function Player (name, stopAtValue) {
  this.name = name
  this.stopAtValue = stopAtValue
}

let player = new Player('Player 1', 16)
```

I thought of using a Deal function:

```
function deal () {
  if (shuffledDeck.length > 1) {
  return shuffledDeck.shift().value
  } else {
  return null
  }
}
```

I then get the value of the shifted card and can use that to calculate the score with.
The problem is, how can I create a loop that deals the card until the added value reaches the limit. I thought of something like this:

```
do { 
  deal()
  } while (deal().value <= Player.stopAtValue)
```

Any pointers on what kind of loop I can use for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `deal()` returns the value of the first `Card` in the array, not the cumulative score of the player. You're also referring to the `stopAtValue` of the `Player` function, which doesn't exist. Instead, you should be referring to the `stopAtValue` of the initialized `player` object. I would add a `currentScore` property to the `Player` function and make the deal function add to that instead.

**Player:**

```
function Player (name, stopAtValue) {
  this.name = name
  this.stopAtValue = stopAtValue
  this.currentScore = 0
}

let player = new Player('Player 1', 16)
```

**Deal:**

```
function dealTo (player) {
  if (shuffledDeck.length > 0) {
    player.currentScore += shuffledDeck.shift().value
  }
}
```

**Loop:**

```
do { 
  dealTo(player)
} while (player.currentScore <= player.stopAtValue)
```

Comment: You said *"The problem is that deal() returns the value of the last Card"*, no it returns the value of the first Card in the array.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I would based the loop count on the player's `stopCount`, otherwise what's the point of having it.

```
let player = new Player('Player 1', 16);
var valueReached = false;

while (!valueReached){
  if(player.stopAtValue >= deal()) {
    valueReached = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your `deal()` function returns a `number` by `shuffledDeck.shift().value` and you were trying to access a `value` property in `deal().value`, which will throw up an error.

The solution whould be to return the whole `Card` object in your `deal` function and then get its value, and store this value in a temp variable and compare upon it in your loop condition.

And make sure to reference the `stopAtValue` of the created `player` instance instead of the `Player` constructor in `Player.stopAtValue` in your loop.

This is how should be your code:

```
function deal () {
  if (shuffledDeck.length > 1) {
     return shuffledDeck.shift();
  } else {
     return null;
  }
}

var lastValue = 0;
do{ 
   lastValue = deal().value;
} while (lastValue && lastValue <= player.stopAtValue);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var shuffledDeck = [{
    value: 13,
    name: 'K',
    suit: '♥'
  },
  {
    value: 9,
    name: 'Q',
    suit: '♥'
  }, {
    value: 20,
    name: 'J',
    suit: '♥'
  },
  {
    value: 13,
    name: '10',
    suit: '♥'
  }
];

function Player(name, stopAtValue) {
  this.name = name;
  this.stopAtValue = stopAtValue;
}

let player = new Player('Player 1', 16);

function deal() {
  if (shuffledDeck.length > 1) {
    return shuffledDeck.shift();
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

var lastValue = 0;
do {
  lastValue = deal().value;
  console.log(lastValue);
} while (lastValue && lastValue <= player.stopAtValue);
```